# S3 bucket mount on wowza vod not streaming after few seconds

Tags: amazon-s3, wowza

I have wowza 4.4.0 & ffmpeg installed on two different ec2 instances.
ffmpeg trancodes the .dav videos and convert them in .mp4 extension, then it uploads the file in s3 bucket.
same s3 bucket is mounted on wowza server at /usr/local/WowzaStremingEngine/Content using s3fs, i am streaming the videos from the mounted s3 bucket folder.
sometimes vod play smoothly, whereas mostly vod stucks after playing for 2-3 sec.

I also tried playing vod directly from s3 bucket, but that was too slow

Comment: this may due to connectivity issue. is you ec2 and s3 are in same region ?.

Comment: No, they are not in same region.

Comment: try with same region s3. I suspect this is connectivity issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying a different source file as well. Use the sample.mp4 file that comes default with your Wowza install and upload it to your s3 bucket.  See if you are experiencing the same issues then.

If that remains an issue,  you could look at increasing the [DefaultBlockSize](http://www.wowza.com/resources/WowzaStreamingEngine_MediaCacheUsersGuide.pdf) (page 25) within your MediaCache configuration.  I'd suggest trying 1-2M and decrease the readahead threshold, restart and try again

Comment: I did defaultBlockSize to 2M and readAheadThreshold to 15, but it does not work.

Comment: I uploaded sample.mp4 and it streaming great but my transcoded file does not. As I mentioned for transcoding, am using ffmpeg. ffmepg video codec is libx264 with bitrate 1024 and audio codec libmp3lame with bitrate 128k.

Comment: Sounds like it definitely has to do with the encoding then.  What is the full command you are using?